# How many distinct solutions are there?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose you put the numbers $1,2,\cdots ,10$ in each of the boxes below
[image]

such that every connected row and column sum to the same number. How many distinct solutions are there? (By distinct we mean disregarding cyclic permutations, reflections, etc.)

I tried this problem and found only one solution, namely $4,5, 1,10,8,2,3,6,9,7$ when read clockwise starting on the top leftmost square. I tried to prove it's unique but failed (miserably).

From experience, I know algebra isn't the best way to approach these types of problems, due to the number of variables and the symmetry of the equations. When trying to find $3\times3$ magic squares, for example, it'd be best to brute force all the possibilities rather than trying to solve a $9$-variable system.

So does anyone know how to solve this (preferably without guess-and-check)? Any help is welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: "How many unique solutions are there?" Just one. If there's more than one, then it's not unique.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is "different" (or "distinct" or "distinguishable").

Comment: Here is another solution: $3,1,10,5,8,6,4,2,7,9$.

Comment: @bof I agree with you: unfortunately nowadays the word "unique" is often used with this incorrect meaning, particularly in the expression "this site has had $n$ unique visitors since $d.m.y$."

Comment: A couple of more or less obvious observations: $10$ and $9$ cannot be in the center of either row, since then the row sums must be at least $22$ and there is then no way to get both columns to sum to $22$. Second, the sum of the numbers in the middle of the two columns is odd; by the first point, it must be at least $13$, so it is $13$, $15$, $17$, or $19$.

Comment: @rogerl The sum of the numbers in the middle of the columns could also be $11$, for example, $10,1,5,6,7,9,2,3,8,4$.

Comment: @David You are right, and in fact there are solutions of that form.

Comment: First, there is one transformation that you might not want to consider different: if you replace each number by $(11-$ that number$)$ you have a solution.  

A useful thing to note is that if you add all four sides you get the sum of all the squares plus the corners a second time.  This must be a multiple of $4$.  Since the sum of all the numbers is $55$, the sum of the corners must be $1 \pmod 4$

Comment: Also, you can reverse the numbers in the middle of either long row to get another solution.

Comment: @RossMillikan Re: $11-{}$ that number, this is not correct because of the different number of squares in the rows and columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete answer but just a few observations which are too lengthy for a comment.

Let $t$ be the total of the numbers on any one side of the rectangle, let $c$ be the sum of the four numbers in the corners, let $s$ be the sum of the two numbers in the middle of the short sides (columns) and let $l$ be the sum of the four numbers in the middle of the long sides (rows).  Then

- $c+s+l=55$;
- $3c+2l+s=6t=3c+2s+l$, so $s=l$;
- $4t=55+c$, so $c\equiv1\pmod4$;
- $2t+l=55$, so $l$ is odd.

Taking into account the possible ranges of the variables, the options we have at this stage are
$$\matrix{
  c={}&13&17&21&25&29&33\cr
  t={}&17&18&19&20&21&22\cr
  s=l={}&21&19&17&15&13&11\cr}$$

Answer (score 0):

There are ten solutions
\begin{align*}
  &1,4,5,9,7,3,2,6,8,10 \\
  &1,4,7,6,10,2,3,5,8,9 \\
  &1,5,6,7,9,3,2,4,10,8 \\
  &1,5,7,6,9,4,2,3,10,8 \\
  &2,3,6,9,7,4,1,5,10,8 \\
  &2,3,8,5,9,4,1,7,6,10 \\
  &3,1,10,5,8,6,2,4,7,9 \\
  &3,2,5,10,6,4,1,7,8,9 \\
  &6,1,5,10,4,8,2,3,9,7 \\
  &6,3,5,8,4,10,1,2,9,7
\end{align*}
which turn into $40$ distinct solutions when the numbers in the middles of the upper and/or lower rows are reversed. These are all the solutions, regarding rotations and reflections as the same.

Comment: I'm not really interested in the solutions themselves, but how you get them. Like I said, this would help me in many other problems similar to this one.